# vs code command 'extension.insertColonOrSemiColon' not found

Tags: visual-studio-code

This happens during anytime I hit enter during the preselection of an object to quickly fill out the rest of the line of code...

[image]

Comment: disable all your extensions and see if it still happens, also look at your keybindings, read on the doc page how to debug a keybinding

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks. I come to find out IT at my work removed some of my extensions and corrupted the others that weren't removed. I just uninstalled and re-installed that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Here it worked after removing the "vscode-styled-components" extension from wsl.

I can't claim it's an extension bug or a problem on my machine. More reports from other users would be required.

Comment: And that solved it for you? Are you saying this is a bug in that extension?

Comment: I use VS Code Remote Development and the "vscode-styled-components" extension there. I had had the same warning, which was gone only after reloading the extension on the remote machine.